# Using aria2 instead of curl breaks string concatenation

Tags: bash, find, path, aria2

I am trying to mirror a site to `archive.org` but using `curl` is very slow so I wanted to try `aria2` instead.

I first make a link map of the site using this command

```
wget -c -m --restrict-file-names=nocontrol https://www.example.com/
```

and then run this command using curl

```
find . -type f -exec curl -v "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';'
```

(Actually I used this command to get a good enough log of what I was doing

`find . -type f -exec curl -v "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';' 2> >(grep 'Rebuilt URL' >>/tmp/error ) >/tmp/stdout` - included it here for reference)

This was working fine, the find-command produced output such as

```
./www.example.com/index
```

and curl magically ignored the leading `./`

Well, Aria2 wasn't so smart. This command

```
find . -type f -exec aria2c -x 16 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';'
```

lead to this error:

```
07/24 23:40:45 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=https://web.archive.org/save/https://./www.example.com/index
```

(Note the extra **`./`** in the middle of the URL).

I then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596462/how-to-strip-leading-in-unix-find) that helped me modify the output from find

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n'
```

returns

```
www.example.com/index
```

(no leading `./`)

However, when feeding this to aria2 the concatenated URL **still** contains `./` in the middle!?!?

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n' -exec aria2c -x 16 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';'
```

gives this error message

```
www.example.com/index

07/24 23:52:34 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)
[#d44753 0B/0B CN:1 DL:0B]                                                                                     
07/24 23:52:35 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=https://web.archive.org/save/https://./www.example.com/index
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=29 URI=https://web.archive.org/save/https://./www.example.com/index
  -> [HttpSkipResponseCommand.cc:232] errorCode=29 The response status is not successful. status=502

07/24 23:52:35 [NOTICE] Download GID#d44753fe24ebf448 not complete: 

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
d44753|ERR |       0B/s|https://web.archive.org/save/https://./www.example.com/index
```

How do I get rid of the `./` so aria2 is fed proper and correct URLs?

Bonus questions:

1. It would be great if I could (re)move the pages after processing their URL. That is, move index from `./www.example.com/index` to `./processed/www.example.com/index`. How do I do that? Something in the `exec` of the `find` command? Or does that require a full fledged script?
2. What are the optimal settings for aria2 for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one doesn't work because the `-exec` is independent from `-printf`.

But you can use `xargs` instead of `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n' \
    | xargs -I{} aria2c -x 16 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}"
```

You can also let multiple `aria2c` instances run in parallel with `xargs -P <num>`.

---

An even better option would be to create a file descriptor from `find` as input for `aria2` instead of using pipes and `xargs`.

```
aria2c -x 16 -s 1 -i <(find . -type f -printf 'https://web.archive.org/save/https://%P\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `-printf` will just produce output, it will not modify what `{}` is replaced by.

It seems `curl` is a bit smarter (or, alternatively, applies more magic) than what `aria2` is, and removes the `./`.  The initial `./` in the found pathname comes from the fact that `find` will produce pathnames relative to the top level directory that you start the search from.

To call `aria2` or `curl` with an URL that does not contain the initial `./`, use

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        pathname=${pathname#./}
        aria2c -x 16 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

This will call a child shell with a bunch of found pathnames.  The child shell will loop over these and remove the initial `./` using a standard parameter expansion before calling, in this case `aria2c`.

In general:

```
topdir=/some/directory/path  # no '/' at the end

find "$topdir" -type f -exec sh -c '
    topdir="$1"; shift
    for pathname do
        pathname=${pathname#$topdir/}
        aria2c -x 16 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://$pathname"
    done' sh "$topdir" {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)