# How to optimise Aria2 when downloading thousands of small files?

Tags: find, parallelism, multithreading, aria2

My starting point is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458296/using-aria2-instead-of-curl-breaks-string-concatenation). Now aria2 is downloading the files but it is not as fast as I expected it (I am running this on a Macbook Pro with an i7, gigabit connection and AC-wifi. I am most definitely not maxing out any of these links of the chain.).

I use aria2 with these switches

```
-x 16 -s 1
```

Since the files are small I see no reason to open several sockets (-s 1) for each download. However, parallell downloading (-x 16. 16 is max, isn't it?) of several files should increase the overall speed, shouldn't it?

Nevertheless, when I read the output log, the downloads doesn't seem to be parallell. Am I missing something in how one use aria?

Or is it the feed of URLs into aria that is the bottleneck (I use find . -t f and then use the result to build the URL fed into aria using string concatenation)?

Answer (score 2):

Opening multiple connections will not help you much when you only send one download to `aria2c` and when the file sizes are small. But you can easily let multiple `aria2c` commands run in parallel using `xargs -P <num>`

Make sure that `-P` value is not more then is allowed by the server, otherwise the server will return an error.

---

```bsh
find . -type f -printf '%P\n' \
    | xargs -I{} -P6 aria2c -x 1 -s 1 "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}"
```

---

Or let `xargs` add all URLs to just one `aria2c` call:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec 'https://web.archive.org/save/https://%P\n' \
    | xargs aria2c -x 16 -s 1
```

---

But I think the best option would be to create a file descriptor from `find` as input for `aria2` instead of using pipes and `xargs`.

```bsh
aria2c -x 16 -s 1 -i <(find . -type f -printf 'https://web.archive.org/save/https://%P\n')
```